# Point multiple domains to one website on IIS7

Tags: iis

This is not SEO related in any way please do not post any thing about SEO ranking as it is not a factor here.

I have 2 urls

old.websitename.com and new.websitename.com

I need to support both urls for a certain length of time and rather than creating 2 sites in IIS I wanted to see if there was a way of doing this by hosting just a single site.

I can not do any redirects on the urls and both urls will need to be active eg I can not have a user go to old.websitename.com and be redirected new.websitename.com. if they go to old.websitename.com they need to stay on that url and not be redirected in any way.

Can this be done on IIS 7 (note this is IIS not Apache or PHP based)

Answer (score 23):

You just need to create a binding for each hostname.

1. Right click the site. "Edit Bindings"
2. Click Add
3. Enter the hostname
4. Repeat 1-3 for each hostname.

Comment: Does adding a new binding restart the existing app? Would it be safe to do this in production or would it require momentary down-time while the binding is updated?

Comment: @styfle adding bindings does not recycle the worker process. It is safe to do in prod.