# Point multiple URLs to a same web application on IIS website?

Tags: asp.net, iis, hosting, windows-server-2012

I have multiple web applications on my IIS, say,

http://localhost/app1
http://localhost/app2
http://localhost/app3

I want a URL http://localhost/myurl to point to http://localhost/app1. how can i do that in IIS? i am using Windows server 2012

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11287947/point-multiple-domains-to-one-website-on-iis7

Comment: I do not want to add URL mappings for my website. the website name remains the same.. its the application's name which i want to change

Answer (score 2):

The other simplified way is fron only 4 steps as follows

1. In Visual studio -> Right click the project in solution explorer and 
      Publish Your web application using File System with the Folder name 
      (myurl)
2. Go to IIS-> Under the Default Web site ->Right Click -> Add Virtual 
      Directory -> Give the alias Name as (myurl) -> Give the physical path as the folder which you created in point no #1
3. Click Ok -> Right click on the (myurl) -> Convert to application
4. Now Browse from IIS-> You will get the Result as you expected

Answer (score 0):

The solution you can do is to create a Virtual Directory Application , you should do it like this:

1. Open the Visual Studio in Administration Mode
2. Right click on the Project in solution explorer -> Properties -> web -> 
      Click on the Radio button Use Local IIS Web Server-> Give the Project URL 
      (http://localhost/myurl)
      and click on the Create Virtual Directory
3. Right click the project in solution explorer and Publish Your web 
      application using File System
4. Go to IIS-> Under the Default Web site -> Refresh -> You can see the Virtual Directory you created (myurl)
5. Right Click on the Virtual Directory-> manage application -> Advance Settings -> Change the Physical path to the folder where you have the published files
6. Now Browse from IIS-> You will get the Result as you expected